# can't running project when add springsecurity.taglib.xml

Tags: spring, security, jsf, spring-security, glassfish

i've problem when implement spring security and jsf 2.0, exactly when add springsecurity.taglib.xml in web.xml

server : glassfish server 3 
springframework 3.0.2 
jsf 2.0

library : 
org.springframework.faces.sources 3

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"          xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>HelloWorldExampleWithSpring3MVCInEclipse</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**springsecurity.taglib.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
<namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
<tag>
    <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
    <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
</tag>
<function>
    <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
    <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
<function>
    <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
    <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
<function>
    <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
    <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
<function>
    <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
    <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) </function-signature>
</function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

**this is error message**

```
In-place deployment at D:\Project\Secret Project\Hobic Project EE\Yeah\build\web
deploy?path=D:\Project\Secret Project\Hobic Project     EE\Yeah\build\web&name=Yeah&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3
D:\Project\Secret Project\Hobic Project EE\Yeah\nbproject\build-impl.xml:760: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 29 seconds)
```

**server error message**

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:    ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document:     jar:file:/D:/Project/Secret%20Project/Hobic%20Project%20EE/Zest/build/web/WEB-  INF/lib/org.springframework.faces-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Class 'org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener' is missing a  runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContext
```

**your suggest right** [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContext], and i got new error now :(

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:  ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [security.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-config.xml]; nested exception    is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml]
```

**solution [Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml]] **

```
![.jar needed][1]
```

can you give suggest for my problem ?
thx agung

Comment: The error looks related to Netbeans configuration and not with the web.xml entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Netbeans, so I don't know its ins and outs, but this error message seems to indicate that some error/exception has been occurred beforehand. Is there really not anything more into the build log?

Anyway, not sure if that solves the problem and is related to the concrete problem, but one thing which caught my eye is that your `<facelet-taglib>` is declared conform Facelets 1.x while you're using JSF 2.x which has Facelets 2.x bundled. Netbeans might have fallen over that.

Fix the root declaration of `.taglib.xml` file as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0"
>
    <!-- Config here. -->
</facelet-taglib>
```

Further, Glassfish is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, but your `web.xml` root declaration complies Servlet 2.5. This should technically also not immediately cause a problem, but you'll miss Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 advantages this way.

I'd fix the root declaration of the `web.xml` as well:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    version="3.0"
>
    <!-- Config here. -->
</web-app>
```

---

**Update** as per your update the root cause of your concrete problem seems to be the following:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContext

The `NoClassDefFoundError` means that the in the message mentioned class is missing in the classpath, while it is (indirectly) required by other classes in your application. The solution would be to add the class (or in this particular case, the JAR file with the class) to the classpath. The mentioned class is part of [Spring WebFlow](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow). You need to download it and include it in the classpath (the buildpath as the IDE calls it) the same way as you did for the core Spring framework and Spring Security.

---

**Update 2** as per your second update, a new problem appeared after fixing the first:

> Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security] Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml]

I'm no Spring guy so I can't answer that from top of head, but [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unable%20to%20locate%20Spring%20NamespaceHandler%20for%20XML%20schema%20namespace%20%5Bhttp://www.springframework.org/schema/security%5D) suggests that this problem is caused by a missing [Spring Security Config](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html) JAR file.

Comment: hii BalusC - thx for your response. i'd try your suggest to change/fix taglib.xml & web.xml but when i try to build/run it's still not work... <br/>hope any suggest again thx –

Comment: Oh, the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContext` is pretty self-explaining, isn't it? The JAR containing the mentioned class is missing in buildpath. The package suggests that it's part of Spring Webflow.

Comment: i got new error message in the server and i've put it in above, please check...thx

Comment: ok, so what can i do no now for solve this problem ?..#sorry i'm newbie..:D

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContext it SOLVED, now error in app-config/ security.xml, error message please see update

Comment: See answer update. This should technically be asked as a new question :)

Comment: ok thx so much BalusC, i like you analysis and suggest - this very helpful for me, and i hope can solve this problem...once again thx..:D